# Importing problems with webpack/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, scrollmagic

I am trying to import this module called `debug.addIndicators` for `ScrollMagic` in a React project. This of course means I have to use es6 so I add to my

```
import "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js";
```

which causes a compilation error with the error

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
> '/home/david/.steampath'] {   errno: -2,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall:
> 'stat',   path: '/home/david/.steampath' }

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for imports, assuming they're in node_modules and the package was built and published correctly, is

```
import identifier from 'package-name'
```

To import something that performs a side effect, when you don't need an identifier, as in this case:

```
import 'package-name'
```

To import a named export, it would be

```
import { foo } from 'package-name'
```

Note that in all these cases, the module name is a string, and in none of these cases can you import a property on an object which is a named export, because dots are not an acceptable part of an identifier. This is why the other two answers have SyntaxErrors. To get that item, you could instead do this:

```
import { foo } from 'package-name'
const { bar } = foo
```

---

In the case of ScrollMagic, that means

```
// import the default export from the package
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
// import the plugin you want
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators'
```

The reason this works is that the package-name resolves to somewhere in node_modules, and then to whatever's specified in the `main` or `module`  fields in that module's package.json.

There's also a React-specific version, which you can get with `npm i react-scrollmagic` and import with

```
import { Controller, Scene } from 'react-scrollmagic'
```

This wrapper also has the plugin you're trying to import.

Or, as was mentioned in the comment on your question, you could use the recommended library, [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/).

Comment: I did the import plugin the exact way you did it, still doesn't work.

Comment: In what way does it not work — are there errors, or something else going on? I just did a barebones test with minimal config and it imported just fine.

Comment: React won't compile it and gives me the error I stated in my post. Removing that import fixes it however so I am confused.